# App Engine logging.debug Not Being Logged on Server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, logging

For some reason, I do not see debug log messages on the **production server** when I use the `logging.debug` function. The `logging.info`, `logging.warning` and `logging.error` functions work just fine. I am using django on app engine and have the following settings in my `settings.py` file:

```
def config_logging(in_dict):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(
        level = logging.DEBUG,
        format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    )

LOGGING_CONFIG = "settings.config_logging"
```

Also note that when I use the `--debug` flag on the development server, the proper logs are displayed.

I can't figure out why debug logs are not being recorded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if something in django differs for this, but you need to include `--debug` as a flag when you start the server to see debug-level log messages in a non-django app.

Comment: Your answer is for the dev. server, right? The issue is occurring on the live server too.

Comment: I meant to say production server in my question, not dev. server. I fixed that.